# Client not amenable to invoicing of third party client onboarding

Tags: contracts, group-freelancing

They prefer to have me bill at the end of the project, and are claiming that it makes it harder to bill their third party clients for their project if I'm sending multiple invoices. Thoughts? I need the money, but also I made it Net 30. The client pays within a week so they've said (it's a new client of mine), but even then it'll be 3 weeks since I started doing new third-party client introductions. It's a single-member company and I'm definitely helping them with these new clients, because I have the expertise. I do kind of need the money but I'm not forcing them to pay right away. idk, I feel silly. I guess we had tentatively agreed to do end of project, but I didn't expect to log the time simply meeting and interviewing.

Comment: What is the question you want answered here? This is simply a listing of the situation.

Comment: As far as I can see, In short, you're assuming all of the client-side risk here. If the client chooses not to pay you (or disputes the bill), you'll have to sue them for the cash. If they go broke or simply disappear from view, you'll have spent x months working on a project for no return. This sort of arrangement is generally referred to as "*You setting yourself up for a fall*"

Comment: @DavidR - I'm guessing the implicit question is "Was this wise?", to which the answer is "No! What are you, a glutton for punishment?". It does, however, feel very opinion-based in its current configuration. I've edited to make what I think the question is (e.g. *"Can I bill early and what will the likely fallout be?"*) a bit more explicit

Comment: Hi guys, so the person did come through. We'll see how regular the work is. It's supposed to be a long-term thing. So.. since they insist on paying end of project, I've insisted on 20% down on estimated work.